# entering int or float using input()

Tags: python

I need to enter different values to `input()`, sometimes `integer` sometime `float`. My code is

```
number1 = input()
number2 = input()
Formula = (number1 + 20) * (10 + number2)
```

I know that `input()` returns a string which is why I need to convert the numbers to float or int.
But how can I enter a float or integer without using `number1 = int(input())` for example? because my input values are both floats and integers so I need a code that accepts both somehow.

Comment: Why not just make all the inputs floats? If the inputs will always be real numbers within a pretty large size and precision, it doesn't make a difference except for the output type.

Comment: Is the input trusted? Then you could simply use `eval(input())`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379966/6045800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your inputs are "sometimes" ints and "sometimes" floats then just wrap each input in a float(). You could make something more complex, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the presence of a decimal point in your string to decide if you want to coerce it into a `float` or an `int`.

```py
number = input()

if '.' in number:
    number = float(number)
else:
    number = int(float(number))
```

Comment: This'll fail on scientific notation like `1e10` as well as special values `nan` and `inf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use `float`:

```
number1 = float(input())
```

If you'd like to cast any of your result to integer you always can easily do this

```
int_res = int(res)  # res was float; int_res will be an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 = float (input(‘ enter first value  ‘) )

number2 = float (input(‘ enter second value ‘) )

Formula = print ( (number1 + 20) * (10 + number2) )
```

Comment: Be careful with so-called "smart quotes", e.g. `‘’`. They'll cause `SyntaxError`s with Python.